# Benefits of using custom CursorRecyclerViewAdapter over copying cursor contents to ArrayList then pass to RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I was recently working on an App where cursor data are copied to ArrayLists then these ArrayLists being passed to subClass of RecyclerViewAdapter because RecyclerView doesn't have CursorAdapter like ListView.

With further reading, I found many answers recommend using @skyfishjy following custom CursorRecyclerViewAdapter:

[CursorRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59)

Which eventually copies the contents of the Cursor to ArrayList to use its data with the ViewHolder in overridden method onBindViewHolder.

The question here, if the cursor data will be copied to ArrayLists anyway, why not copying them in first place then working with RecyclerViewAdapter? What are the benefits of using this custom CursorRecyclerViewAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

It simplifies the work. Nothing much. There is no specific advantage other than saving some time by writing the same logic